# Espressioni alternative a 'è un must'

Tags: grammar, phrase-request

> Oggi la diversificazione geografica *è un must* per le imprese, non una semplice alternativa.

Credo che *è un must* sia un'espressione piuttosto comune, della quale sopra è riportato un esempio d'uso.

Siccome a me non piace, ho spesso cercato  locuzioni alternative quali *è un obbligo*, *è un dovere* e cosi via, ma ho l'mpressione che queste non 'suonino' fresche, dinamiche e leggere come l'originale inglese.

Credendo che non ci siano adeguate parole  italiane per sostituire *must*, sono chedere se ne conoscete qualcuna latina che sia, pero, in uso relativamente corrente.

Ho pensato anche al tedesco 'diktat', in uso nell'italiano, ma non credo funzioni, e, comunque, non mi piace.

Comment: Si potrebbe usare: '... è fondamentale per le imprese ...' indicando qualcosa che sta alla base e sui cui costruire. In più non suona come un obbligo.

Answer (score 6):

Alle alternative gia proposte, *"è fondamentale"* ed *"è imperativo"*, che mi sembrano buone scelte, vorrei aggiungere *"è d'obbligo"*.

"È un obbligo" da l'idea di qualche implicazione legale o regolamentaria.

Answer (score 5):

Io ho sempre visto l'espressione **è un must** collocata in un contesto ben specifico. Lo codificherei con un'azione che dev'essere eseguita per fare le cose secondo i canoni di *best practices*, *seguendo un protocollo*. Una condizione sine qua non la tua azione non arriverà facilmente agli standard di qualità.

Ciò detto, io utilizzerei vocaboli come *importante* o addirittura *fondamentale* a seconda del contesto e di che messaggio si vuole trasmettere.

Comment: Potresti specificare meglio quale sarebbe il contesto specifico? Io l'ho sentito dire nelle situazioni più disparate: in un contesto formale, come l'esempio della domanda, finanche a situazioni decisamente informali/scherzose come *i pop corn durante il film sono un must!*.

Comment: Sì, sono d'accordo con te: la piega che ha preso è quella che prendono tutti i fenomeni massificati. Mi viene automatico pensare che l'ingresso nel nostro comune modo di esprimerci abbia avuto l'incipit in un contesto che potrei definire "di business", per cui nella ricerca dell'eccellenza le grandi compagnie internazionali abbiano definito dei protocolli di "must do" e noi italiani, seguendo il loro esempio, abbiamo mantenuto parte del loro modo di definire i vari "bullet" da seguire.

Comment: È intuibile che una parola come must che viene insegnata nelle scuole come la forma più forte di dovere abbia ottenuto facilmente un ruolo da protagonista.

Answer (score 3):

Si potrebbe usare la traduzione *è un dovere* ma, almeno alle mie orecchie, questa suona meno "forte" che l'originale inglese.

L'utilizzo di *è un obbligo* è sicuramente più forte, ma aggiunge l'idea di un'imposizione ad es. rispetto ad una legge etc.

Sicuramente ci sono altre possibili traduzioni ma direi che *è una [scelta/condizione/politica/...] irrinunciabile* rende piuttosto bene il significato di *a must*.

Infine, volendo passare al latino, probabilmente si potrebbe usare *condicio sine qua non*.

**EDIT**: come da suggerimento di randomatlabuser, *è un imperativo [categorico]* è un'altra ottima soluzione.

Comment: «È un imperativo», «È un imperative categorico»?

Comment: @randomatlabuser: vero, niente male!

Comment: Non ho mai sentito dire «È un imperativo». Semmai «È imperativo». Ad ogni modo, credo che "fondamentale" sia un alterntiva migliore.

Comment: @Bruno9779: nell'espressione "è un imperativo categorico", *imperativo* è un sostantivo, ed è una derivazione della [filosofia Kantiana](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperativo_categorico) (che nella lingua comune ha forse perso un po' il suo significato originale). Nell'espressione *è imperativo*, invece, *imperativo* è un aggettivo.

Answer (score 2):

> Oggi la diversificazione geografica è un must per le imprese, non una semplice alternativa.

Io userei *è irrinunciabile*:

> Oggi la diversificazione geografica è irrinunciabile per le imprese, non una semplice alternativa

Dato poi che la frase afferma "è questo e non è il contrario di questo", si può togliere la parte dopo la virgola senza alterare il significato

> Oggi la diversificazione geografica è irrinunciabile per le imprese.

Poi sistemerei la forma per rendere la frase più lineare

> Per le imprese di oggi la diversificazione geografica è irrinunciabile

Comment: La parte dopo la virgola non cambia il significato generale della frase, ma decisamente lo enfatizza.

Answer (score 1):

"È d'obbligo"  é la espressione più usata in questa occasione